# Ionic app loads using Ionic serve but not with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm currently stuck on a problem related to my Ionic project.

I have an Ionic project on GitHub which i've been working on in the past few weeks, i have a few Cordova plugins as part of the project.

When downloading the project from GitHub, i can run the app using Ionic Serve without a problem. However, when trying to setup the project for xCode to run on local device(s), i run into a multitude of errors

Some include:

1. When running ionic 'cordova platform add ios' the following error appears

> **Error:** Could not install from "ios" as it does not contain a package.json file.

2. When trying to run 'ionic cordova run ios -l --external'

> **Error:** Error: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have not yet tried to transfer my code into a new Ionic project, as i wish to see if my problem can be solved without that hassle.

View project code here: https://github.com/designsheikh/bitsandbobs.git

Comment: Have you tried wiping the `node_modules` and removing the `package-lock.json` ?

Comment: Yes, the issue still persists.I can still continue development, however i will not be able to test any plugins such as the imagePicker or Camera when needed. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it working now ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I made a new project and transferred the code over, the same issue persists. Im not really sure where the issue is

Comment: I recently got the same error when trying to add the android platform. It was somehow caused by a corrupted project architecture. Is there a way you could share your project so I can check it out ?

Comment: I have added the GitHub repo above - thanks

Comment: It seems as if all my ionic projects have this issue, not only this.

Comment: @Reqven Just wanted to ask if you managed to have a look at the code if you were able to spot the issue with the project architecture?

Comment: @CodingJunkie I have not been notified of your messages because you didn't tag me. Thanks for the repository, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You have the exact same issue I've had with the `android` platform.
As I pointed it out in the comments, it is indeed caused by a "corrupted" project architecture.

#### How it happened

Initially, I had an issue with the cordova generated resources, somehow not being copied into the `android` platform directory. I tried plenty of things with the `cordova-res` CLI, including using the `--copy` and the `--ios-project` flags to force the copy to happen in the directory of my choice.

I couldn't manage to fix my issue, and then decided to rollback all my changes and start over on a clean project to try something else. Since then, I was not able to add the `android` platform anymore. Every single time, the following error was being thrown :

```
Error: Could not install from "android" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

#### Explanation

With all my testing, I noticed that when using `cordova` to add the platform or copy the resources over, somehow, it had created the `android` platform in the wrong directory, at the `root` of my project instead of in the `platforms` folder. And that's where the issue comes from.

I can't explain it, but you will encounter this error every single time if you try to add a platform with `cordova` while having a folder with this platform name at the root of your project. I have no idea why this would prevent a platform from being added to the project, maybe this folder is used as a `temp` folder by the CLI.

#### Solution

The fix is to simply remove any `ios` or `android` directory at the `root` of your project.
The error will go away and you will be able to add the platform again.

---

[@CodingJunkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6047227/codingjunkie)

Regarding the Github repository you provided in your post, you will likely run into another error while trying to add the `ios` platform if you use `cordova@>=9.0.0`.

```
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "xcode" is not supported.  
Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
```

Check this [issue#1033](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1033) for a workaround. However, it's not recommended to directly edit the plugin source code, you might want to look for another cordova Firebase plugin.

I also noticed you kinda mixed up `cordova` and `capacitor` in your project.
Make sure to use one or the other to avoid potential errors.

**Hope this helped !**

Answer (score -1):

@Reqven

Thank you for your support! - i was sure that i had done this step while trying to fix the issue. It is such an absurd problem, it seems that there is a new project architecture as you mentioned which needs to be followed. I followed your steps with also one minor additional step as im working on the iIOS platform:

1. Delete iOS folder
2. cordova platform add ios
3. cordova prepare ios
4. ionic build

If step 2 throws an error causing the version not to be found or integrated into the project run - include '@latest' this also solved my problem